# Cassandra is column-based or column-oriented?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, difference

1. What are differences between column-based or column-oriented?
2. Is there any differences for Cassandra about two of them?
3. Please give example for each of them?

Comment: From my perspective column-based or column-oriented is the same thing. Maybe you wanted to know the difference between row oriented and column oriented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Column-based and column-oriented are essentially the same thing.  Essentially, data for specific columns is stored together to make querying that data faster, as well as scalable.  Examples of columnar DBMS products are: [Druid](http://druid.io/druid.html), [MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/), and [Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/).

In terms of how Cassandra relates, the answer to that is that **it doesn't**.  Cassandra is a ***partitioned row-store***.  Column values are stored by partitions and rows.

You are not alone in this perception, as many people mistake Cassandra for a "columnar" data store.  Earlier versions of Cassandra were considered "schemaless," so that may be where some of the confusion originates.  But Cassandra has never embraced a storage model which keeps data for specific columns together.